# How to test a virtual postgres 9.6 server will be greater than a physical postgres 9.6 server

Tags: postgresql, migration

We have a physical postgres server running on 9.6, I am looking to virtualize this server, but want to if possible utilise old postgres WAL logs if its doable?

Is it possible to replay the same transactions against the virtual server (this will be a test) in order to see how it performs?

I had seen online about a PG extension called pgreplay - if this is an option would I have to amend the postgres logging for the physical server?

Am basically looking to prove that a virtual server will be better performing than a physical one. As our database grows we will inevitably have issues with space, easily added if was virtual but difficult for physical.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "a virtual server will be better performing than a physical one" -- that is unlikely.

Comment: @mustaccio even if the virtual server had more CPUs/Memory?

Answer (score 2):

Replaying WAL is quite different from replaying a database workload. One obvious point is that `SELECT` statements usually are not WAL logged.

pgreplay can provide a reasonable test, but you will have to modify the logging configuration for your current database to generate a log that can be replayed.